# Export a document as a PDF via app script api

Tags: api, google-apps-script, pdf-generation

Is there a way to export / serve a document as a PDF via the API in google app script?

I know there exists a download as pdf option, but I am not looking for that. I am looking to create a PDF document in google drive via the app script API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Try the [File.getAs() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String))

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

```
oOutputFile.saveAndClose();
DocsList.createFile(oOutputFile.getAs('application/pdf')).rename(cOutputName+".pdf");
```

where oOutputFile is my Doc, and cOutputName is the name I want to give to the file.

Chris